# How to share global variables across multiple octave scripts?

Tags: global-variables, octave

Suppose I have three octave scripts `a.m, b.m, c.m`, and two global variables `x, y`.  Is it possible to define these global variables in such a way that they can be shared across scripts?  For example in a separate include file?

More Generally, how do global variables in GNU octave work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you have to declare the variable global, and you *also* have to explicitly tell Octave that the variable you are referencing is in a different (global) scope.

in library.m

```
global x = 1;
```

in main.m

```
function ret = foo()
    global x;
    5 * x;
endfunction
```

foo() should return 5

Answer (score 2):

### How to use global Variables in Octave:

Make a file called tmp.m and put the following code in it.

```
global x;   %make a global variable called x
x = 5;       %assign 5 to your global variable
tmp2();     %invoke another function
```

Make another file called tmp2.m and put the following code in there:

```
function tmp2()
  %the following line is not optional, it tells this function go go out and get
  %the global variable, otherwise, x will not be available.
  global x 
  x
end
```

When you run the above code like this:

```
octave tmp.m
```

You get this output:

```
x =  5
```

The global variable x was preserved in tmp.m and retrieved in tmp2.m

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

A file with global variables `globals.m` with:

```
global my_global = 100;
```

And just use `source` inside each file. For example:

```
source globals.m

global my_global

printf("%d\n", my_global);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best solution, but I ended up creating a wrapper script, from which all the other scripts are called.  I put my globals inside that wrapper script